# Different subject and body for different mails in single Mandrill API call

Tags: mailchimp, mandrill

I am using Mandrill API(ruby) for sending mail. In 'rcpt' option I can give multiple email address.

Is there a way to change Subject according to email address?

Ex..

```
"to"=>
        [{"type"=>"to",
            "email"=>"user1@email.com",
            "name"=>"User1 Name"},
         {"type"=>"to",
            "email"=>"user2@email.com",
            "name"=>"User2 Name"}],
     "metadata" => {                
        },
```

I want Subject like this

```
"Hi, #{username} you have a new mail"
```

Similarly is it possible to make dynamic email body according to email-address?

Answer (score 1):

### This seemed to have worked for me

[image]

I am a front-end dev and I was tasked to set a custom subject in mandrill.

So what I found was, in order to put dynamic content in the body of the email, I had to use double curly braces `{{ client_name }}` in the code.
This was already linked to variables that have been created by backend...

The task was to make the **subject**
the same as the client name with an added message like this...
**"Hi John, hope you are well"**

So I found that when logging in to Mandrill and going to your template,
You have the option to set your subject there...

Assuming your backend variables have been set up, you can actually use double curly braces in Mandrill where you set the subject

So my final result in Mandrill itself, looked like this

**"Hi `{{ client_name }}`, hope you are well."**

This seemed to have worked for me, however I did not set up all the variables in the backend, but this might help some of you at least.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible (or I didn't find the way) to send different subjects in one call
Only one subject can be set according to the documentation and my tests
https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.ruby.html#method=send-template

For dynamic content you can set variables in your template for example *|TITLE|*
and replace it in your code using merge_vars

```
merge_vars: [
          {
            rcpt: @user1.email,
            vars: [
              {name: "TITLE", content:"#{@user2.full_name} sent you a new message"}
            ]
          },
          {
            rcpt: @user2.email,
            vars: [
              {name: "TITLE", content:"#{@user1.full_name} well received your message"}
            ]
          }
        ]
```

The only solution for me is to make to calls using the same template but different parameters